# In Bash's builtin "read" command, is there a way for it to accept whitespace as input

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

My Google-fu is failing me here.

If I have a token of "hello world " and then use it as stdin for bash's builtin read, I will get the trailing whitespace truncated. Is there a way to preserve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that you have to set the variable $IFS to newline. This is what I did, and it worked

```
$ read x
hello world 
$ echo $x"testing"
hello worldtesting
$ IFS='\n'
$ read x
hello world 
$ echo $x"testing"
hello world testing
```

The manual says, and I quote, ahem:

> If IFS has a value other than the default, then sequences of the
>   whitespace characters "space" and "Tab" are ignored at the beginning
>   and end of the word, as long as the whitespace character is in the
>   value of IFS (an IFS whitespace character).

Sources: [info on read itself](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) & [info on word splitting](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_07)

Comment: It's better to set IFS only for the read command by setting IFS as a prefix to it (this won't mess up other things that depend on IFS).  Also, you can just set IFS to null: `IFS= read x`